# Нужна ли запятая после скобок?

Tags: пунктуация

*В случае если билет не продан (например, произошло зависание системы и т. д.) подтверждение оказания услуги банку-эмитенту карты не поступает, банк-эмитент в установленный правилами банка срок возвращает денежные средства пассажиру.*

Answer (score 1):

Запятая *нужна* — для отделения придаточного предложения от главного. Кроме того, для присоединения предложения с подлежащим "банк-эмитент" после имеющейся запятой требуется союз **а** или **и**.

Comment: Не требуется. Может стоять, но не требуется.

Comment: Не требуются ни А, ни И: вставить даже силой не получается. Если смысл позволит, проходит лишь вариант с оборотом ЕСЛИ.., ТО.

Comment: Союз после запятой требуется здесь по _смысловым_ причинам: выбор одного из этих союзов позволяет отнести присоединяемое предложение (как следствие) либо к общему придаточному (вариант с "а"), либо ко всему предшествующему высказыванию (вариант с "и"). Присоединение же через _запятую_ (как в исходном варианте) оставляет неясность и делает само присоединение безосновательным. Второй смысловой вариант возможен и без употребления союза, но при отделении точкой с запятой или точкой (соотв. паузы в устной форме).